# How to annotate a class to factory function converter

Tags: typescript, generics

[Typescript playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Greeter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20greeting%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(message%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.greeting%20%3D%20message%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20greet()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22Hello%2C%20%22%20%2B%20this.greeting%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20greeter%20%3D%20new%20Greeter(%22world%22)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20noNew%20%3D%20%3CT%2C%20U%20%3D%20new%20(...a%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20T%3E(clazz%3A%20U)%3A%20%7B%20(...b%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20T%20%7D%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20clazz(...args)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D)

I'm trying to annotate a function which takes a class and returns a factory function that returns instances of that class. (Basically, it removes the need to `new`).

Here's what I came up with:

```
const noNew = <T, U = new (...a: any[]) => T>(clazz: U): { (...b: any[]): T } => {
    return (...args: any[]) => {
        return new clazz(...args);
    };
}
```

This doesn't work for at least two reasons:

1. I get a "Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature." error with `return new clazz(...args);`.
2. I don't get any type completion or type checking for the constructor parameter arguments.

How would I rewrite this not produce errors and to have the parameters type-aware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is simple to fix, you don't actually need `U` you can just use `clazz: new (...a: any[]) => T`

The second problem is a bit more complex, and there isn't a perfect solution. To get the parameter types, you will need to define function with multiple signatures, one for each length of the constructor parameter list:

```
function noNew<T>(clazz: new () => T): { (): T } 
function noNew<T, T1>(clazz: new (arg1: T1) => T): { (arg1: T1): T } 
function noNew<T, T1, T2>(clazz: new (arg1: T1, arg2: T2) => T): { (arg1: T1, arg2: T2): T } 
function noNew<T, T1, T2, T3>(clazz: new (arg1: T1, arg2: T2, arg3: T3) => T): { (arg1: T1, arg2: T2, arg3: T3): T } 
function noNew<T>(clazz: new (...a: any[]) => T): { (...b: any[]): T } {
    return (...args: any[]) => {
        return new clazz(...args);
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
class AA {
    constructor (){}
}

class BB {
    constructor (a: string){}
}

let d = noNew(AA)();
let b = noNew(BB)("");
```

It works except for the case when you have optional parameters, then `noNew` returns a function that only keeps the required parameters and removes the optional ones.

```
class BB {
    constructor (a?: string){}
}
let b = noNew(BB)(); // No arguments
```