# How to annotate a function which takes a class and returns a factory with static members?

Tags: typescript, annotations, static-methods

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48695757/how-to-annotate-a-class-to-factory-function-converter), but I want static members on the class to also be available.

This is what I'm trying:

```
function noNew<T>(clazz: new () => T): { (): T }
function noNew<T, T1>(clazz: new (arg1: T1) => T): { (arg1: T1): T }
function noNew<T>(clazz: new (...a: any[]) => T): { (...b: any[]): T } {
    const factory = (...args: any[]) => {
        return new clazz(...args);
    };

    // I want the return type annotation to be aware of this step
    Object.assign(factory, clazz);

    return factory;
}

class Test {
    static one() {}
    two: 'two';
}

const test = noNew(Test);
test.one(); // <- unresolved function or method 'one'
```

As you can see, typescript doesn't know that I added static members to the return value. How do I represent this as an annotation?

Bonus points if you can exclude `test.prototype`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
// works for some constructor types
type ConstructorToFunction<C extends new (...args: any[]) => any> = (
  C extends (new () => infer T) ? () => T :
  C extends (new (a: infer A) => infer T) ? (a: A) => T :
  C extends (new (a: infer A, b: infer B) => infer T) ? (a: A, b: B) => T :
  C extends (new (...args: any[]) => infer T) ? (...args: any[]) => T :
  C // bail out
) & { [K in Exclude<keyof C, 'prototype'>]: C[K] }
```

Here I'm using [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) introduced in TypeScript 2.8 to try to represent the transformation of a constructor to a function with the same arguments.  The big conditional part takes the place of your set of overloads, and the intersection with `{[K in Exclude...` takes care of copying the static parts.

Here's how I would type the `noNew()` function:

```
function noNew<C extends new (...args: any[]) => any>(
  clazz: C
): ConstructorToFunction<C>;
function noNew(
  clazz: new (...args: any[]) => any
): { (...args: any[]): any } {
  const factory = (...args: any[]) => {
    return new clazz(...args);
  };
  Object.assign(factory, clazz);
  return factory;
}
```

The single overload is still helpful because functions returning conditional types are hard to implement without lots of type assertions, so the overload frees me from that.

Let's see if it works:

```
class Test {
  static one() { }
  two: 'two' = 'two';
}

const test = noNew(Test);
test.one(); // works
```

Looks good.  Hope that helps!

Comment: My solution was 1/10 as good as this. Thank you :). The `prototype` property is still coming through, however. The playground link I have is too long to fit here :(

Comment: Is the `prototype` of type `any` and not `Test`?  If so, it's not coming through.  All functions have a `prototype` property, according to the [TypeScript standard library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.8.3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L288).